# reload current page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a session variable that changes some things about how a page looks. I have a button that changes the value of this session variable. But ... the onClick event happens after page load, so by the time I update the session variable based on the button click, it's too late, the page has already been loaded.

Theoretically I could put all the logic about changing the display into a function and call it from page load, and then call it again from the onclick after the variable as been updated. But this is impractical: there are many user controls that check the value, used on many different pages in different combinations. I would have to hard-code the list of user controls on each page, and if someone added a new user control to a particular page, they'd have to remember to update this function, which is lame.

Is there a way to force a page reload? (I can use response.redirect back to myself and it works. If all else fails I guess this is what I'll do. But it means an extra round trip to the server, which is clumsy.)

Is there a way to process the onclick before the page load?

Some other magic solution?

Comment: In On_click set value in session variable and make a redirect call for the same page Response.redirect("YourPage.aspx")

Comment: @EmaadAli - Read the question. This option has been mentioned by the OP.

Comment: I know it. I got this idea so i mentioned it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to change the look and feel of a page based on a specific value which can change, then you should have dedicated functions that set up the look and feel in a single unified place, and then you call those functions in every case where a value that affects the look and feel is called.

Examples:

```
private void SetDivVisibility()
{
  // display logic here based on variables

}

private void MyControl_Click(...)
{
   myvalue = blah;
   SetDivVisibility();
}
```

It helps to bear in mind that the actual rendering of the page is last thing that happens, after both page load AND event processing.

Comment: The catch to that is that there are about 15 user controls that test the flag to alter their appearance, and different pages use different combinations. So I'd have to keep a separate list of what controls are on each page to know which ones to modify, and it would have to be updated when a page is changed. That seems a maintenance error waiting to happen.

Comment: Each page *already* knows what controls live on it.  Thus each pages "SetDivVisibility" or "SetLookFeel" whatever can contain calls to each control's "SetLookAndFeel" method.  Your controls can know HOW to change how they look, but the PAGE should tell them WHEN to test to change their appearance because it's the page that knows when values have changed.

Comment: Well, obviously ASP knows what controls are on a page. Is there a way to get my hands on the list? Of course I'd still have to have a way to "retroactively" identify which controls were affected by the state change. Actually I'm refactoring now to make them user controls rather than undistinguished asp:hyperlink's.

Comment: Get your hands on a list?  If you're working on the page, you should know what controls are on that page, shouldn't you?  I'm not sure I'm understanding your question.

Comment: Sure, but I've got many pages with many combinations of affected controls. Some are user controls nested inside other users controls. Yes, I could go through all the pages and figure out which controls are on each, and then hard-code this list within an update function. But then if months from now someone else comes along and modifies a page, they'd have to remember to update this list. That's a maintenance trap waiting to snap.

Comment: Well, not the answer I wanted to here, but I'll give you the prize for effort, anyway. Maybe there is no easy way to do what I want.

Answer (score 2):

> Theoretically I could put all the logic about changing the display into a function and call it from page load

That's how you **should** do it. Cleanup your logic and markup - refactor and keep it [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). That should help.

> I can use response.redirect back to myself

That's the other option. Yes, a round trip is nasty.

Answer (score 0):

you may put your code of styling your page in a void called by the page_load normally and called again from buttonclick

or call response.redirect to same url

or even onClick is client side use window.location.href

Answer (score 0):

A design with a layout predicated on the existence of a session variable which won't exist until after it's been render is a huge design error.  I like to call it the "Chicken or the Egg" syndrome. (yes, you can quote me.. ;)

I'd argue that your controls shouldn't get their layout completed in the on render.  Instead, use a method (similar to databinding) where you can "rebind" the controls with the new session value on demand.  This method would show/hide things based on the updated values.

Comment: I agree with the principle of what you're saying, but how? The controls have to be included in the aspx markup. And then they'll get build at onload time. Well, I suppose I could write code to dynamically add them to the document tree separately from the plain aspx page, but I really don't want to do that. I did that with a bunch of Javascript once and it worked but it was super ugly.

Comment: @Jay: See Oded's answer.  He's dead on.  Basically, the properties of the controls should be set during the page_load.  Once those properties are set, then you call a method that causes the control(s) to show/hide whatever it is they need.